# Spring singleton service and prototype method lookup injection

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a singleton service class like the below:

```
@Service
public class SingletonClass {

    // the context is prototype scope
    private Context context;

    public void run(){
        context.setXyz();
    }

    public void runThis(){
        context.getXyz();
    }

    // setter,getter methods for context
}
```

How can I achieve this in a thread-safe way with a lookup-method injection?

I want to share the state across methods. Get new context with every method and used in subsequent methods.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your Singleton class as follows

```
    @Service
    public abstract class SingletonClass{

     protected abstract Context createContext();

     private Context context;
     @PostConstruct
     public void init() {
     context = createContext();
     }

     public void run(){
     context().setXyz();
     }

     public void runThis(){
     context().getXyz();
     }

     public void runThisWithNewContext() {
     createContext().getXyz();
     }
     }
```

And your xml config will look like,

```
     <bean id="context" class="Context" scope="prototype" />
     <bean id="singletonClass" class="SingletonClass">
       <lookup-method name="createContext" bean="context" />
     </bean>
```

Comment: if i go with above solution,  public void runThis(){
     createContext().getXyz();
     } - here it will create a new context instead of getting existing context. isn't it?

Comment: yes, it will create new instance every time `runThis()` is invoked

Comment: I want to store the state as instance vars and can we manage state in a multithreaded environment? is there any way spring provides out of the box solution for this?

Comment: i had edited my answer as per your requirement, please check whether it works

Comment: if its inside init() it will be called only once isn't it? it will become singleton rather than prototype in this case

Comment: yes, but whenever you want a new instance you could invoke `createContext()`  to get a new one. edited the answer, look at it.